# Graphing the Mandelbrot set using the C curses library

Tags: c, curses, fractals, mandelbrot

I am having trouble drawing the Mandelbrot set with Curses. I am looking mainly at this tutorial: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2358/how-to-plot-the-mandelbrot-set/mandelbrot-set.
My screen ends up just outputting rows of the same character even when I follow the logic of the program that they wrote. Does someone know what is going wrong?

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mandelbrot(int c) {
    int z = 0, n = 0;
    while (abs(z) <= 2 && n < 100) {
        z = z * z + c;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

int main() {
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    int MAX_Y, MAX_X;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, MAX_Y, MAX_X);

    for (int bi = 0; bi < MAX_Y; bi++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < MAX_X; a++) {
            int growth_factor = mandelbrot(a / 10);
            if (growth_factor == 100)
                mvprintw(bi, a, "#");
            else
                mvprintw(bi, a, "*");
        }
    }
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: You should be using `double` instead of `int`.

Comment: Debug it a bit. Check the coordinates, do they make sense?

Comment: @dbush `double` instead of `int` where?

Comment: Why use `a / 10` instead of a coordinate? This `mandelbrot` function is a simplified version of what [I've written (`test_point`)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217574/ascii-mandelbrot-set-image-producer), but it seems odd to pass a single integer into a function that should be expecting a complex number.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The coordinates don't make a lot of sense. I'm getting a number in the range of 1 to 3 or 100 (which doesn't give me much detail).

Comment: Do you know the [basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Basic_properties) of the set? How could be  an `int` a proper type for `z`?

Comment: You need to scale the screen coordinates `bi` and `a` to `double` values `y` and `x` in the range `-2.0 <= x,y <= 2.0`, and pass *both* coordinates to the iterator function, which must compute with `double` (but not quite like you did it). Then for now, output a character `' ' + iterations`.